# SQL left join error in laravel query builder

Tags: laravel, query-builder

My code is selecting all data from teachers table and showing only id's from connected tables instead of nations name. when i try to select any table except teachers it doesn't work.

```
  public static function teacher($id)
  {
   return DB::table('teachers')
   ->leftjoin('nations', 'teachers.nation_id', '=', 'nations.id')
   ->select('teachers.*')
   ->where('teachers.id',$id)
   ->first();
  }
```

**when i add;**

i)   `return DB::table('teachers','nations')`
 ii)  `->select('teachers.*','nations.nation')`

it is selecting nothing from nations table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
public static function teacher($id)
  {
   return DB::table('teachers')
   ->leftjoin('nations', 'teachers.nation_id', '=', 'nations.id')
   ->select('teachers.*','nations.nation')
   ->where('teachers.id',$id)
   ->first();
  }
```

Comment: i already tried it, but with your suggestion i tried again and it worked.

Comment: @iscpreee great!